# Google Maps Shows Up Grey

Tags: android

I know this has been asked before but I have read/tested for hours and I can't get my maps to show up! I generated the md5 and registered it which gave me the key I use in the code below. PLEASE HELP!!!!!!
Here is the androidmanifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.libertytech.locatemycar"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity android:name=".Home"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.libertytech.locatemycar.GoogleMap" android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.libertytech.locatemycar.Test" android:label="@string/app_name"
              >
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.Internet"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>
```

Here is the googlemaps.xml

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="006_T_R2vy70wILMHcCnAGiZoOe7jVjYM_xYtXA"
/>
```

All the required xml tags seem to be in the correct place. I have internet on the phone (I can browse the web). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I needed to use `android.permission.INTERNET` not `android.permission.Internet`! It would be nice if Google could have given an error about missing permissions or something useful. It would have saved me hours and hours of work!

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a check list. please ensure these things are correctly followed.

1. Build Target platform used: It should be of Google API
2. Emulator: You should use emulator of target Google not Android.
3. MD5 Key: It should be generated from the same machine in which you are compiling the application.
   Also follow how to get mapview on the application detailed in this link: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: 1)I did set the build target. I have "Google APIs" checked with an api level of 7 which is the minSdkVersion too. The application would not even launch if that isn't set.          2)I am not using an emulator I am using an HTC Incredible.     3)I am generating the MD5 key from the same machine that I am compiling on.

Answer (score 0):

To get the app working in the emulator, then using an API key key generated from the debug keystore is OK.

To run the app on a phone you need a different Google API key; this must be generated from a private keystore which you have explicitly ***signed***.

See section 1 of this link  [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)
for details

Comment: I am not releasing this to the app store yet. I am connecting the usb cord to my pc and phone and deploying the app to the phone. I have read the link you provided and I don't think this is the issue. I am using Eclipse and Eclipse uses the debug by default.

Comment: Eclipse uses the debug key by default, but you still need to get the key Google provides for that debug key. Without it, it won't even work no matter you are trying it only for yourself. They are different things, you need the map key associated with the debug key.

Comment: This is the MD5 key generated from the debug keystore:CF:ED:24:FA:81:28:CA:EF:E6:8A:A6:23:46:98:46:1F then I went to the google registration page and used that to get the api key 006_T_R2vy70wILMHcCnAGiZoOe7jVjYM_xYtXA. That is the key in the example above. Are you asking me to do something different or in addition to what I have already done?