# MapView not working [android]

Tags: android, android-mapview

When I load my MapView application, the MapView only displays the grey grid lines.

Here is my Code:

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="0aOphT3vlZFVSL1HZ2Vg-RmIDhH0nPlp8e7gJrg"/>
```

**Manifest File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.andoid.googlemaps"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
        <activity android:name=".GMapsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

**Activity:**

```
package com.andoid.googlemaps;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class GMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       /* Proxy Settings*/
        System.setProperty("http.proxySet", "true");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy.example.com");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Why do you have a proxy? Is that the proxy you are actually using?

Comment: yes i am working in a proxy net.

Comment: yes i already done that.

Comment: Please go through the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079316/google-maps-shows-up-grey/6079781#6079781

Answer (score 0):

See the following link on displaying google map. This may help you

[Tutorial on How to use Google map](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

Answer (score 0):

The API key used for the map **depends** on the certificate used to sign your application.
You **must** follow the following instructions to get a valid API key.

> The Android Maps API lets you embed Google Maps in your own Android applications. A single Maps API key is valid for all applications signed by a single certificate. See this documentation page for more information about application signing. To get a Maps API key for your certificate, you will need to provide its the certificate's fingerprint. This can be obtained using Keytool. For example, on Linux or Mac OSX, you would examine your debug keystore like this:

See [Sign Up for the Android Maps API](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html).

This often means that you need a key for debug-builds and another for release-builds (signed application package for Android market for example).

Answer (score 0):

After a long time its worked. But still not got where was the problem actually,nothing i changed just i shared debug.keystore with my friend and its worked. Any way thanks for the reply...